# Android native extension - Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView'

Tags: admob, google-play-services

Trying to make an android native extension (ane) with an AdMob banner for my AIR project.

Problem is, when i run the final apk on my phone, Eclipse DDMS gives me an error:

Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView' referenced from method blah blah

And the AdMob banner does not appear.

Looks like google play services somehow are not included, or not accessible.

I know my extension is working, because i can add a native android text or a button on top of my AIR project and they appear on the phone, but AdMob banner does not.

Also if i make apk with only android (no AIR), the banner appears just fine.

I am using
JDK 1.8
Google Play Services rev 24
Android SDK Tools rev 24.2
target=android-22
Eclipse 4.4.2

Been trying to solve this for a week, nothing i tried helped.

Whatever you'll suggest, i will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't building the .ane file right.

This blog helped me and I got it working:

http://jmsliu.com/2143/add-admob-ads-in-flash-based-android-apps.html

Specifically, i had no idea i had to include:

**google-play-services-res**: this folder contains all resource required by google play service lib. It is copied from google play services lib. You can get all this from Android SDK)

**android-support-v4.jar**: this java library is copied from google play services lib

**google-play-services.jar**: this java library is copied from google play services lib

through platform options xml file:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/4.0"> 
    <packagedDependencies>
        <packagedDependency>android-support-v4.jar</packagedDependency>
        <packagedDependency>google-play-services.jar</packagedDependency> 
    </packagedDependencies> 
    <packagedResources>
        <packagedResource> 
            <packageName>com.google.android.gms</packageName> 
            <folderName>google-play-services-res</folderName> 
        </packagedResource> 
    </packagedResources>
</platform>
```

Somehow I was thinking that users already have google play services on they Android phones and there is no need to include all those libraries and resources. Still don't understand why they are needed. Apparently, you need both: 1. to include gogle play services libs and resources; 2. users to have google play services installed on their phones.

Comment: while this link may answer the question.It is necessary to quote useful parsts of teh answer as link only answers may became invalid if link expires or changes.